# Custom form validation in laravel 5.4 wihtout using AppServiceProvider boot() method

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, php-7

Currently I have a form I am validating like so:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        \Validator::extend('custom_validation',function($attribute, $value, $parameters){
             //validation logic
      });
    }
...
```

But is there a way I avoid having to place this method in the `AppServiceProvider` (or any service provide for that matter)?

Is there a way for me to insert it somewhere in the controller class for example (for simplicity's sake)?

I like a variant like using a making a request class (extending `FormRequest`) but not sure how to add the custom method to the request class.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you care for the `$parameters` argument passed in the Closure in the implementation of your validation logic?

Answer (score 0):

Factor out the validation rule into a class that implements `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule` contract. (See the section about "Using Rule Objects" <sup>[1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules)</sup>.)

```
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class CustomValidation implements Rule
{
    public function passes($attribute, $value) 
    {
        // validation logic
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'validation error';
    }
}
```

Then have a custom form request extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest` <sup>[2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation)</sup>

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\Rules\CustomValidation;

class CustomFormRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // include rules for other fields
            'custom' => new CustomValidation,
        ];
    }
}
```

Carryout validation in the related controller using rules declared in your custom form request by type hinting the request on the controller method

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CustomActionController extends Controller
{

    protected function create(CustomFormRequest $request)
    {

    }
}
```